# Get ID from `<input>` tag using a combined `.match` call

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a string like this

```js
`<input id="test_name" name="test_name" type="text" list="auto_search_complete" value="" placeholder="Search">`
```

And I just want to get the `id` value which is `test_name`. I use this code:

```js
var str = '<input id="test_name" name="test_name" type="text" list="auto_search_complete" value="" placeholder="Search">';
var id = str.match(/id=\"\w+\"/g)[0].match(/\w{3,}/g);
```

Is there any other ways to combine two `match` calls into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

If the regular expression contain capturing group, [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return an array which contains whole matched string and captured groups:

```
str.match(/id="(\w+)"/)
// ["id="test_name"", "test_name"]
```

You can get desired one by index:

```
str.match(/id="(\w+)"/)[1]
// => "test_name"
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I used `g modifier` so that the result just had `id="test_name"`

Answer (score 3):

Don't.

You're using JavaScript, you have a DOM and HTML parser right there for you.

```
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = '<input id="test_name" name="test_name" type="text" list="auto_search_complete" value="" placeholder="Search">';

var id = tmp.children[0].id;
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Regex expressions allow you capture groups of text using parentheses. Then the respective elements of the result of calling the `match` function contain the grouped elements.

If you want to access what \w+ matched, just wrap it in parentheses. So,

```
var id = str.match(/id=\"\w+\"/g)[0].match(/\w{3,}/g);
```

becomes

```
var id = "";
var results = str.match(/id=\"(\w{3,})\"/);
if (results) {
     id = results[1];
}
```